# pyvim UpdateVirtualSwitch return "A specified parameter was not correct"

Tags: python, esxi, pyvmomi

I'm trying to update virtual switch security setting via python but failing with message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "VPC_CRS-Compliance-Remediation-ESXi.py", line 787, in <module>
    main()
  File "VPC_CRS-Compliance-Remediation-ESXi.py", line 771, in main
    current_setting(hosts, "check")
  File "VPC_CRS-Compliance-Remediation-ESXi.py", line 653, in current_setting
    host.configManager.networkSystem.UpdateVirtualSwitch(vswitchName="vSwitch0", spec=switch.spec)
  File "/root/pydev/py36-venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pyVmomi/VmomiSupport.py", line 706, in <lambda>
    self.f(*(self.args + (obj,) + args), **kwargs)
  File "/root/pydev/py36-venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pyVmomi/VmomiSupport.py", line 512, in _InvokeMethod
    return self._stub.InvokeMethod(self, info, args)
  File "/root/pydev/py36-venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pyVmomi/SoapAdapter.py", line 1374, in InvokeMethod
    raise obj # pylint: disable-msg=E0702
pyVmomi.VmomiSupport.InvalidArgument: (vmodl.fault.InvalidArgument) {
   dynamicType = <unset>,
   dynamicProperty = (vmodl.DynamicProperty) [],
   msg = 'A specified parameter was not correct: ',
   faultCause = <unset>,
   faultMessage = (vmodl.LocalizableMessage) [],
   invalidProperty = <unset>
```

I'm trying to set it like this:

```
for host in hosts:
    if host.runtime.connectionState == 'connected':
        #set_port_grp_security(host)

    security_policy = vim.host.NetworkPolicy.SecurityPolicy()
    security_policy.allowPromiscuous = False
    security_policy.macChanges = False
    security_policy.forgedTransmits = True
    network_policy = vim.host.NetworkPolicy(security=security_policy)
    switch = vim.host.VirtualSwitch.Config()
    switch.spec = vim.host.VirtualSwitch.Specification()
    switch.spec.policy = network_policy
    a = host.config.network.vswitch
    for i in a:
        print(i.spec.policy.security.allowPromiscuous)
        print(i.name)
        host.configManager.networkSystem.UpdateVirtualSwitch(vswitchName=i.name, spec=switch.spec)
```

I can't find any example how this should be updated correctly anywhere everybody is either creating or removing stuff, nobody is updating :D any idea how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

This did it for me ( its called in function, parameter for function is a host object from vim.HostSystem):

```
   switches = host.config.network.vswitch
   # attept to set security policy
   for vswitch in switches:
       host_id = host.configManager.networkSystem
       specs = vswitch.spec
       specs.policy.security.allowPromiscuous = var_allowPromiscuous
       specs.policy.security.macChanges = var_macChanges
       specs.policy.security.forgedTransmits = var_forgedTransmits
       host_id.UpdateVirtualSwitch(vswitchName=vswitch.name, spec=specs)
```

Took me for ever to figure out, hope it helps somebody....